# Windows Surface on-screen keyboard will disappear when focusing on password input

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard, passwords, tablet-pc

**Background:** I have users who commonly access a site using Windows tablets. The tablets do not have external keyboards connected and the web page is accessed using a bookmark to utilize the browsers web-app/kiosk mode. Their browser of choice is Chrome.

**Issue:** Windows Surface's on-screen keyboard is hidden when focusing on a password input in the Chrome or IE11 browser.

```
<input type="password" />
```

The on-screen keyboard will display as expected when focusing on a regular text input.

Browser does **not** need to be in the bookmarked web-app/kiosk mode to reproduce.

This issue does not occur when using the Edge browser.

**Demo to reproduce:**
[https://codepen.io/MacArmstrong/pen/QxvOKx](https://codepen.io/MacArmstrong/full/QxvOKx/)

Comment: we've had this issue for over a month and ended up creating our own password field from a regular input text field. Basically replace the characters with `*` on the fly, while appending the input characters to a string variable.

Strange we're not hearing much about this bug - it started after a recent Windows keyboard update.

Comment: FYI, here is a link to the Chrome issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=843932&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=touch%20keyboard%20windows&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified%20Opened&groupby=&sort=